# How to Configure: Window Azure Load Balancing between instances?

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure

I have 2 instance in windows azure. I am finding that only one instance is under use. How to tell/configure windows azure to use both instances in round robin way or any other way?

Comment: What kind of services are they running? Are they 2 instances of the same configuration or two differently configured machines?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you're finding only one instance under use?

Comment: I have the same issue. One role - two instances. One is only utilized. I have a public domain with a CNAME set to the cloudapp.net domain. I can tell only one is used by looking at the monitoring graph, rdp'ing into each and looking at the resource monitor and even NewRelic...all show that the second instance isn't getting any traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's two instances of the same Role, and you're accessing that role through its cloudapp.net dns name (or some custom dns name mapped to cloudapp.net), then the load balancer takes care of that for you; no ability to configure it. You'd see traffic across both instances.

If it's two instances of the same role, but you're accessing them through internal endpoints, it's up to you to choose which instance to talk to.

If it's two instances spread across two different roles, load-balancing doesn't come into play, as you only have one instance of each role.

Comment: I need to disable the automatic and configure it myself.

Comment: You cannot configure the load balancer yourself in Windows Azure. And your original question asks how to configure the LB to distribute traffic across all instances, which is exactly how the LB works. Each instance must be considered stateless, with no instance affinity.

Comment: But why there is no traffic in instance 2? I need round robin.

Comment: Please see my comment on your original question: you need to provide more detail about this: type of role, how you've come to this conclusion (maybe logfile snippets), what traffic you've driven to your role to determine this, etc. Otherwise there's no way to help.

Comment: I ma using simply web role. NOthing special

Answer (score 1):

If they are instances in the same role, load balancing is automatic.

If you have 2 different roles, with different instances underneath them, then you need to scrap that configuration, upload only 1 role and change the configuration to 2 instances.

Also how are you determining that there is only 1 instance being used?

Comment: I need to disable the automatic and configure it myself.

Comment: Just reading on from your comments above. How are you determining it is only hitting 1 instance and not the other. Logs? If so which ones are you looking at. As previously stated by David you can't control the LB in Azure